# Referencing with Javascript/jQuery the rows of a table that has no id while holding an instance of one of its rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several tables in my page and none of them has an id attribute.

I retrieve with Javascript or jQuery a row of one of these tables. Then I want to do things to all the rows of that table but not to any row of any other table. Selecting such rows through jQuery would do, and also doing that with Javascript would be ok.

So I need to identify a table and the only thing I know about it is that this row belongs to it. Is it possible ?

Runnable example:

```
<html>

<head>

<script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<style>

.myYellow
{
    background-color: yellow;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

function doStuff() {

  var jqRow = jQuery("#r1t1"); if (jqRow.length !== 1) throw "ERROR";

  var htmlRow = jqRow.get(0); // How do I restrict the jqSelectedRows below to only the table this row belongs to ?

  var jqSelectedRows = jQuery("tr.myYellow"); // But I only want the yellow rows of the table containing htmlRow .

  jqSelectedRows.each(function(index) {

    this.setAttribute("style", "background-color: blue");

  });
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

  <table border="1">

    <tr id="r1t1"                 ><td>r1 t1</td></tr>

    <tr id="r2t1" class="myYellow"><td>r2 t1</td></tr>

    <tr id="r3t1" class="myYellow"><td>r3 t1</td></tr>

    <tr id="r4t1"                 ><td>r4 t1</td></tr>

  </table>

  <br><br>

  <table border="2">

    <tr id="r1t2" class="myYellow"><td>r1 t2</td></tr>

    <tr id="r2t2" class="myYellow"><td>r2 t2</td></tr>

    <tr id="r3t2"                 ><td>r3 t2</td></tr>

  </table>

  <br><br>

  <input type="button" value="Do" onclick="doStuff()">

  <br>The button selects the first row of the first table ("r1 t1") and then it
  <br>must turn blue all the <strong>yellow</strong> rows of <strong>that table only</strong>;
  no other table must be affected.

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Look at closest() http://api.jquery.com/closest/  Example usage:  $('tr').closest('table');

Comment: @devlincarnate Interesting. Actually `closest()` looks like the right function to retrieve the table. However I need to retrieve that table just because I need to reference all the yellow rows of that table only, that is excluding any row of any other table. I just edited the question title to better reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**.siblings()**](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/). See comment in snippet.

**Note:** Changed button slightly which of course can easily be converted back to the original way by deleting the code around the `doStuff()` function and adding the `onclick="doStuff();"` back to the `<input>` button.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#do').on('click', doStuff);

  function doStuff() {

    var jqRow = $("#r1t1");
    if (jqRow.length !== 1) throw "ERROR";

    var jqSelectedRows = jqRow.siblings(); // How do I restrict the jqSelectedRows below to only the table this row belongs to? | Use .siblings() to collect all <tr>s within the table (excluding the referenced tr#r1t1). 

    jqSelectedRows.each(function(index) {

      this.setAttribute("style", "background-color: blue");

    });
  }
});
```

```css
.myYellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>32721615</title>
</head>

<body>

  <table border="1">

    <tr id="r1t1">
      <td>r1 t1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="r2t1" class="myYellow">
      <td>r2 t1</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="r3t1" class="myYellow">
      <td>r3 t1</td>
    </tr>

  </table>

  <br>
  <br>

  <table border="2">

    <tr id="r1t2" class="myYellow">
      <td>r1 t2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="r2t2" class="myYellow">
      <td>r2 t2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="r3t2">
      <td>r3 t2</td>
    </tr>

  </table>

  <br>
  <br>

  <input id="do" type="button" value="Do">

  <br>The button selects the first row of the first table ("r1 t1") and then it
  <br>must turn blue all the <strong>yellow</strong> rows of <strong>that table only</strong>; no other table must be affected.

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That was it, thanks. Just a small detail, I needed to select only the rows of the first table that have the `myYellow` class (except the referenced row of course). Your example was selecting the right rows but regardless of whether they had the `myYellow` class, and these rows in my original example happened to also be all the yellow ones, by accident. So, bad example, and I just added one more non-yellow row to the first table to better show this. But I see that `.siblings()` can take a selector so I'm just using `.siblings("tr.myYellow")` and it works perfectly.

Comment: Good catch, I tend to make my answers pertain to a broad range.